# What ASP MVC Telerik component should I use in order to achieve autosuggest combo box with pictures?

Tags: user-interface, telerik, telerik-mvc

My client is using Telerik ASP MVC [ASP MVC](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx) components. So I wonder what particular component should I use in order to achieve autosuggest combo box with pictures (similar to LinkedIn - see the screenshot below)?

[image: LinkedIn autosuggest with puctures]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is actually possible using the [Kendo UI Autocomplete](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html), along with some customizations. We've done this for both the search on the [docs.kendoui.com](http://docs.kendoui.com) site as well as the [Kendo Music Store Sample](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-music-store) and you can check the source of the latter to learn more about how.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

No such component which allows you to template it like this.